# Save the variable in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I am very new in Javascript and trying to learn by experiencing it. Sorry if this question is a multiplication or super-easy one. I am using an open source server and I need to make some additions.. following is the part of code:

```
    /**
 * Event listener
 *
 * @param {SceneJS.node} hit Selected SceneJS node
 */
pick: function(hit) {
    this.unselect();
    this.highlighted = this.SYSTEM.scene.findNode(hit.nodeId);
    var groupId = this.highlighted.findParentByType("translate").data.groupId;
    strID = (hit.nodeId);   
    alert(strID);
........
```

I defined the strID variable as a global. In the final use, I select a node of a 3D model in browser, and the nodeID of the selected element is appeared on screen as an alert. How can I write the selected entity's "nodeId" (or "strID" variable) in a JSON file, and save the file in a folder in local drive. So I can use this JSON file for further steps.

Maybe I don't know which keywords to search.. I checked couple of ways like `JSONstringify` but couldn't succeed. Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check localStorage, to save this data between sessions.

```
localStorage.setItem('strID', strID);
```

and

```
strID = localStorage.getItem('strID');
```

Comment: I believe he's asking how to save the data in Node, not the browser. This only works for front-end JS.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I worked on the locaStorage.setItem and (getItem) and tried pretty much all the possibilities. @PrestonBadeer  I realized that the nodeId does not come as a server response. Can you give me any example for a similar case? or specifically which keywords should I use for a possible solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't read about node, but lets try it:

```
    /**
 * Event listener
 *
 * @param {SceneJS.node} hit Selected SceneJS node
 */
pick: function(hit) {
    this.unselect();
    this.highlighted = this.SYSTEM.scene.findNode(hit.nodeId);
    var groupId = this.highlighted.findParentByType("translate").data.groupId;
    strID = (hit.nodeId);   
    alert(strID);
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("/data/strID", strID, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
    });
........
```

To read it use readFile. It it is giving problems about the data format of strID, use [JSON-JS](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to transform to readable before saving

Comment: I tried the above code. The console gave the following error: 

`Uncaught Error: Module name "fs" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`